# Access main site dll's class and create object from sub site in c#

Tags: c#

I have one dll in my main project location's bin folder at the server, and i have one sub site under the main site,

i want to refer/access the main site's dll  class and create object from my sub site. I will keep my dll's in the main site's bin location only, i dont want to copy the referred dll in the sub site bin folder.

Can any one help how to do this?

Comment: what do you mean by sub-site here please ?

Comment: sub virtual directory under main site

Comment: what the type of your main project ? Website or Web Application ?

Answer (score 0):

From the *Properties* window of the sub web application project, under the *Compile* page change the *Build output path* to `..\bin\`.

Refer to [Creating sub-projects in IIS with Web Application Projects](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2006/07/01/652986.aspx)